# read/write observable doesn't always refresh in input box (Knockout)

Tags: knockout.js

I made a computable observable that read/writes against another observable to sanitize the data.  It works well, except that when I update the value many times in a row with an error, after the first time, the value doesn't refresh itself.

Here is a fiddle with the details : http://jsfiddle.net/Spiky/cdxwE/10/

The computed :

```
this.recommendedValueForDisplay= ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        return this.recommendedValue();
    },
    write: function (value) {
        this.recommendedValue(formatDollarsToNumber(value));
    },
    owner: this
}).extend({ notify: 'always' });
```

In fact, the model value is good (as shown in the simple Div) but the value within the Input box doesn't refresh anymore after first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put too much time on this one not to share.  The key was putting the .extend({ notify: 'always' }); on the BASE observable also, not only the computed one.